Code in docs produces error: Why is newTabBrowser.contentDocument null?
Running the example code from the Firefox docs page about the Browser console.
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_console/index.html
var newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.selectedTab);
newTabBrowser.addEventListener("load", function() {
 newTabBrowser.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = "<h1>this page has been eaten</h1>";
}, true);
newTabBrowser.contentDocument.location.href = "https://mozilla.org/";

Running it gives me the following error.
Uncaught TypeError: newTabBrowser.contentDocument is null
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:5
    getEvalResult resource://devtools/server/actors/webconsole/eval-with-debugger.js:306
    evalWithDebugger resource://devtools/server/actors/webconsole/eval-with-debugger.js:218
    evaluateJS resource://devtools/server/actors/webconsole.js:953
    evaluateJSAsync resource://devtools/server/actors/webconsole.js:846
    makeInfallible resource://devtools/shared/ThreadSafeDevToolsUtils.js:103
debugger eval code:5:1
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:5


Why is the contentDocument null?
I tried running the above code. According to the docs, "It adds a listener to the currently selected tab’s load event that will eat the new page, then loads a new page." Instead it generates an Uncaught TypeError: newTabBrowser.contentDocument is null.

It is null because the selected tab is cross origin from the chrome:// tab you are on.

If your are in a tab such as about:config it will work. I am asking mozilla support for a way to do this and programmatically read all tabs.  Mozilla should bring this feature at least for the developer edition.  It is understood that it would be a security issue to permit it.

That's interesting. I wonder if that was the case when the documentation was written, because it doesn't say anything about the origins being an issue. I wasn't able to get the example code to work even in about:config, but I agree with you that it would be a handy feature.

For me it does work in about:config, make sure your selected tab is about:config in the browser. You will be redirected to firefox page and if you go change url to about:config your page has been eaten.  I am not really sure if it is because of cross origin, csp or another feature, meanwhile I am studding the code to find out. and recompile.

https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/docs/contributor/frontend/csp.md
